# Update when scroll to end of page works ... but keeps updating

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a scroll event in a VueJS component that contains this code. Essentially when I'm reaching near the end of the document, it updates `Jobs()` via AJAX.

```
if ( windowScrollTop >= (documentHeight - windowHeight - 50) )
{
        this.updateJobs();
}
```

Now this works and the jobs update and display. The problem is, that it won't stop; for some reason, it keeps updating until it draws out all pages of data.

I assumed that it would stop after the first update and render as the `if` statement would then be false. However, the scroll event triggers without the various positions and heights being updated to reflect the new position (not at the end of document) with the new data.

Should I just add a `setTimeout` to give it time to render? Is there a better solution?

Comment: windowScrollTop >= (documentHeight - windowHeight - 50)  

Are you sure these are updated every time?

Comment: You can add a check to the if statement e.g. `!loading && (scrollTop >=(...))` and set the value to true in the if clause before calling the `updateJobs` method. Once the success handler inside the said method is called, set the value back to false.

Comment: @NickShvelidze yes it updates

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are using `windowScrollTop >= (documentHeight - windowHeight - 50` which means `windowScrollTop` has 50 chances of being greater or equal to last 50 px of the page height.

So it better you check for  another condition also

```
var scrollUpdateFired = false;
if ( windowScrollTop >= (documentHeight - windowHeight - 50) && !scrollUpdateFired)
{
        scrollUpdateFired = true;
        this.updateJobs();
}
```

then in your ajax's promise sucess callback set the value of `scrollUpdateFired` to `false`

Comment: Thank you! :) This really helped!